# What does REDACTED_US_STATE mean in the google Geocoding API result

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoder, jsonresponse

First time I see this and searching for `REDACTED_US_STATE` in Google gives nothing. I use the [android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView](https://github.com/seatgeek/android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView) witch is An AutocompleteTextView that interacts with the Google Maps Places API. It provide location results and caches selected results in a history file for later use.

What does `REDACTED_US_STATE` mean?

Obviously Massachusetts has been replaced by REDACTED_US_STATE

Doing [Reverse Geocoding by Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id) does not give this output. And now I have problem recreating the same result using the Place Autocomplete.

The Placeid is:

> EjE0Ni0zMiBNYXNzYWNodXNldHRzIEF2ZSwgQ2FtYnJpZGdlLCBNQSAwMjEzOSwgVVNB

The address_component is:

```
    [
   {
      "long_name": "46-32",
      "short_name": "46-32",
      "types": "[STREET_NUMBER]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "[REDACTED_US_STATE] Avenue",
      "short_name": "[REDACTED_US_STATE] Ave",
      "types": "[ROUTE]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "Area 2/MIT",
      "short_name": "Area 2/MIT",
      "types": "[NEIGHBORHOOD, POLITICAL]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "Cambridge",
      "short_name": "Cambridge",
      "types": "[LOCALITY, POLITICAL]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "Middlesex County",
      "short_name": "Middlesex County",
      "types": "[ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2, POLITICAL]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "[REDACTED_US_STATE]",
      "short_name": "MA",
      "types": "[ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1, POLITICAL]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": "[COUNTRY, POLITICAL]"
   },
   {
      "long_name": "02139",
      "short_name": "02139",
      "types": "[POSTAL_CODE]"
   }
]
```

The formated_address is:

> 46-32 [REDACTED_US_STATE] Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA

Comment: Weird, I have different result for this place ID: '
32 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA' and nothing strange in address components.

Comment: i can't either reproduce this anymore, better just filter it and handlel the case